# Different byte[] => same BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

Could someone explain to me how two marginally, but non-trivially, different byte arrays can result in the same BigInteger when using `public BigInteger(byte[] val)`?

How can ...

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigIntegerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BigInteger a = new BigInteger(new byte[] {-1, -1, -1, -1, 123});
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger(new byte[] {-1, 123});

        System.out.println(a.toString(16)+" .equals "+b.toString(16)+" ? "+(a.equals(b)));
    }
}
```

... print true?

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding the JavaDocs, but I don't see where. And I would check the source... but, er, I can't find it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sauce: http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/math/BigInteger.java.html#171

Comment: Thanks! Found what I needed at line 2862. How official are these sources? I seem to remember being able to download the source from Sun, but Oracle only points me to OpenJDK.

Comment: These two are the same for the same reason that 150 is the same as 0150.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use , `new BigInteger(byte[]);`, it locates the non-signed byte in the byte array first and then it collects the the signed byte to get the number value.

In both of your examples, the non signed byte is same i.e. `123`. Signed byte is also same i.e. `-1`. The only difference is that in first example, **you have some extra sign bytes which are getting ignored.**

After collecting signed and non-signed bytes, both of your numbers are representing the same `BigInteger value` and hence `equals` is resulting into `true`.

Comment: OK. Now I understand what is happening, but I don't understand why. Doesn't `Translates a byte array containing the two's-complement binary representation` suggest that only bit 7 of the first byte is the sign bit? Any why does it ignore the following -1's instead of treating them as data?

Comment: @DowntroddenCodeMonkey: `Its based on the fact that any given number will have only one signed byte`. The internal implementation is done using the fact. Your example is `braking that contract hence the unexpected behavior, which is right`. Its similar behavior of overflows. When you assign bigger number than the capacity, you get unexpected behavior. If you turn `other bytes except one to +ve`, your numbers `will not match`.

Comment: Aha! I was unaware of this contract. I naively assumed that `public BigInteger(byte[] val)` could take **any** arbitrary byte[] and return a unique BigInteger. Thanks! I shall bestow upon you the Green Tick.

Comment: @DowntroddenCodeMonkey This is essentially correct but it is not very well expressed. All bytes are 'signed bytes' in Java. `BigInteger` doesn't "locate the signed byte in the byte array first". It *skips* all the leading *sign* bytes (0xff), then the next byte is the first byte of the value, then if those sign bytes existed or the high byte of the value was negative, it treats the result as negative.

Comment: In that case you were wrong. It does not do what you described. It does what I described in my comment above. It skips leading bytes with the value 0xff. *Not* 'negative bytes', and it stops doing that at the first non-0xff byte, *not* the first non-negative byte. You don't seem to understand the difference. Downvote.

Comment: @EJP: Yup. I saw that. It says its its looking for `non-sign` byte. That is the term I used earlier. Then you left a comment as "All bytes are 'signed bytes' in Java". I tried updating my answer accordingly. I restored my answer again.

Comment: Third attempt and it's still wrong. They are all still 'signed bytes'. The term you are looking for is the one I used, 'sign byte', or '0xff byte'. Making up your own terminology, or misusing existing terminology, only causes confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The first one contains the same value as the second one plus a lot of sign extension to the left.